# Prove equivalence of definitions of "dense"

Tags: metric-spaces

Prove that these two statements are **[materially equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence#Relation_to_material_equivalence)** (that is, one statement can be derived or proven from the other). Read below the statements for background information if you need it.

- Given a metric space $M$, $M$ is *dense* if and only if for every point $x\in M$, and for every positive real number $\delta$, there exists a point $t\in M$ (with $t\ne x$) such that $t$ is in the delta-neighborhood $V_\delta(x)$ surrounding $x$.
- Given a metric space $M$, $M$ is *dense* if and only if for every two points $x,y \in M$ and $x\ne y$, there exists another point $t$ that is *between* $x$ and $y$, with $x\ne t\ne y$. *Between* is defined rigorously as $d(x,t)+d(t,y) = d(x,y)$.

## Background Information

### Metric Spaces

A *[metric space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space)* $M$ is a set paired with a function $d\colon M^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ (thought of as “distance”) defined such that for all elements (“points”) $a,b,c \in M$,

1. $d(a,a)=0$ (the distance between any point and itself is $0$)
2. $d(a,b)=d(b,a)$ (the distance between any two points is the same in both directions)
3. $d(a,b)+d(b,c)\ge d(a,c)$ (Triangle Inequality)

Furthermore, a fourth property can be derived from the first three: that $d(a,b)\ge 0$. tl;dp.

### Delta-Neighborhoods

Given a metric space $M$, a point $c\in M$, and a distance $\delta\in\mathbb{R}$, the *delta-neighborhood surrounding $c$* $V_\delta(c)$ is the subset of all $s\in M$ such that $d(c,s)<\delta$. In other words, it's the set of all points closer than $\delta$ units away from $c$. On $\mathbb{R}$, this is visualized as the interval $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$; on $\mathbb{R}^2$, it's visualized as a disc; on $\mathbb{R}^3$, as a ball.

Comment: I doubt that these are equivalent. Let $M$ be the  unit circle.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: more precisely, the unit circle as a subset of $\mathbb R^2$, with the metric inherited from the usual metric on $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: As currently formulated, every metric is dense according to the first definition: take $t=x$. Presumably you want to explicitly disallow this in the definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you call a metric is usually known as a *metric space*, but this is a minor point.

- Assuming that in the first property we also require $t\ne x$ (to make it nontrivial), the property amounts to saying that $M$ has no [isolated points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_point).
- The second definition describes a [convex metric space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_metric_space).

Neither implies the other. On the real line, $[0,1]\cup [2,3]$ has no isolated points, but is not convex. On the other hand, $\{0\}\cup (1,2)$ has an isolated point but is convex (according to the above definition).

If you also required $M$ to be complete in the second definition, then it would imply the first one. Sketch of proof: given $a,b\in M$, let $d=d(a,b)$ and consider the set
$$T= \{t\in (0,1): \exists c \text{ such that } d(a,c)=td, \ d(b,c)=(1-t)d\}$$
If $\inf T>0$, then, using completeness, we can show that $\inf T\in T$, that is there exists $c$ as above with $t=\inf T$. But then convexity is violated between $a$ and $c$. Thus, $\inf T=0$, which implies that $a$ is not isolated.

Comment: I edited my original question so that in the first definition, $t \ne x$, and in the second definition, $x\ne t \ne y$. Does this affect your answer?

Comment: @TestSubject528491 No, that's what I assumed all along.